# Пунктуация в предложении "Поэтому по аналогии "на России" тоже будет верно"

Tags: пунктуация

В публикации **Сайт будет писать "на России" вместо "в России"** есть такая фраза

***Поэтому по аналогии "на России" тоже будет верно.***

Каких знаков препинания в ней не  хвататет?

Answer (score 0):

Написано правильно. Никаких знаков препинания не нужно.

Comment: Ета што? Йхий ответ Чемберлену (я о вопросе)? Месть за Окрайну? То-то мы горюче заплачем...

Comment: типа мести вот здесь http://goo.gl/2qoCGT